# How capture event for browser closing in web applications?

Tags: web-applications

When a web application running and on close the browser window then which event raise?

Answer (score 1):

**onunload** is the event raised when closing the browser window.

How ever this event isn't fired only when closing the browser, that's just one case.

Comment: you also can't depend on it 100% of the time.  If the browser crashes then it won't be sent.

Comment: @tloach: if the browser crashes your options are limited

Answer (score 0):

The web browser doesn't send any notification to the web server when the user closer the window.

Answer (score 0):

You may also be interested in **onbeforeunload**.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer at the thread pointed by Diodeus: basically, you cannot... Lot of browsers just no longer fire onbeforeunload and/or onunload. And even when they do, it is hard to distinguish between page reload, page jump and browser/window/tab closing.