# Open a modal window on browser close?

Tags: jquery, lightbox, modal-dialog, thickbox

I'm trying to open a modal window when the browser window closes.
Is there a way to do this with window events? Thanks.

Comment: What OS?  What language?  What browser?  Seriously?

Comment: Not to mention... why? I would find this rather annoying.

Comment: yeah, I know, it's not really user friendly, but it's for an intranet of a client. they want to do a user satisfaction survey (kind of contradictory). the modal window to accept participation should come up at the end of the visit. 90% of users are employees with windows xp and IE7, the rest is various versions of FF and safari on mac OS.

Answer (score 2):

[onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) is probably your best bet.

Comment: onbeforeunload can't distinguish between browser closing, and navigating to another page...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no: Most browsers don't let you know when the browser is being closed.

See also:

[Java Servlet : How to detect browser closing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299679/java-servlet-how-to-detect-browser-closing)

[How capture event for browser closing in web applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317042/how-capture-event-for-browser-closing-in-web-applications)

Comment: This isn't accurate in my experience. I've been using onbeforeunload for years and almost never run into any issues.

Comment: @Jon: technically Stobor is right, onbeforeunload fires when a page unloads which happens not just when the browser is closing but also when you're navigating away from the page.

Comment: @CptSkippy: That's a good distinction. It's hard to say if the OP was trying to be that specific.

Comment: Thanks guys! That event will do it.
Actually, I need to catch the user closing the browser as well as navigating away.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute whatever you need to with the onunload JavaScript event. I'd probably do a window.open rather than try to create a modal because I think the browser will still close. You could use the onbeforeunload event to show a modal confirming their action if that's what you're hoping to do.